# How can I reference the current UINavigationController from a UITableViewCell in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to go back to the previous view controller when a button in a table view cell is pressed. To do this it is my understanding that I should do something along the lines of:

```
navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
```

However I'm finding it incredibly difficult to find a way to reference the current UINavigationController from this UITableViewCell. I have tried things like:

```
let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController
```

This always returns nil.

Please help me find a way to reference a UINavigationController from a UITableViewCell in Swift 3!

Comment: `self.navigationController` should work

Comment: UITableViewCell has no such variable unfortunately

Comment: I have a referenced viewcontroller and used your code - it works! Cheers @NSDmitry, much appreciated

Comment: You should never do something like this from the view/cell, but only from the embedding view _controller_ (in some delgate method from the `UITableView`)

Comment: Appreciate your comment @AndreasOetjen. Explain to me why it is preferable to use a delegate method from a UITableView in the view controller instead of doing so using a UITableViewCell.

Comment: Because it violates the encapsulation/responsibility of _views/cells_: They should just simply display something and send events to registered targets. They should not know that they are part of a view controller and execute any transitions like navigation controller pushing/popping. Those things are done by _controllers_

Comment: Have a look at unwind segues.  Here is a tutorial https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/

Answer (score 1):

You don't want your custom cell to be responsible for going back in your navigation stack. What if you use this cell again somewhere else but such button is expected to behave differently ?

Instead, create a custom delegate `protocol` for your cell and assign it to the view controller which presents the `tableView`.
 From this controller, you'll get the `navigationController` with a simple `self.navigationController`. It will also improve maintainability, reusability and readability of your code.